# An unhandled exception occurred: Project 'ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab' does not exist.: cannot republish NPM package in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-publish

I have published a NPM package for Angular times ago, see it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab), also the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/JorgeGuerraPires/ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab/tree/master). Now I want to add a couple of new functionalities.

Whenever I give

```
ng build ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab --prod
```

This is the error I get:

[image: Here whenever I try to compile the project for publishing on NPM]

My theory: somewhere, when I created the NPM library, Angular kept the original name of the app, which I cannot remember

I have tried to find it, but no success. Tried to do the command inside the folder of the project, no success.  I am creating another project, and it is working fine, even outside the project founder. This leads to me conclude that it is something specific from this NPM library, something is creating this headache.

Of course, I could rebuild the library. Before, I want to learn from the problem, if possible!

Article I have used to learn to create those libraries [here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1238/complete-beginner-guide-to-publishing-an-angular-library-to-npm).

**angular-errors.log**

```
[error] Error: Project 'ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab' does not exist.
    at BuildCommand.initialize (D:\Amazon ebook (sandbox)\modelos matemáticos na medicina e biologia (ebook)\Miyagi-Do-lab-sandbox\app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:48:19)
    at async BuildCommand.validateAndRun (D:\Amazon ebook (sandbox)\modelos matemáticos na medicina e biologia (ebook)\Miyagi-Do-lab-sandbox\app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:127:9)
    at async Object.runCommand (D:\Amazon ebook (sandbox)\modelos matemáticos na medicina e biologia (ebook)\Miyagi-Do-lab-sandbox\app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:204:24)
    at async default_1 (D:\Amazon ebook (sandbox)\modelos matemáticos na medicina e biologia (ebook)\Miyagi-Do-lab-sandbox\app\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:80:31)
```

**Discussion**

Suggestion #1: "Navigate your terminal to the location of your project and rerun the" from the folder? tried! from several positions.

Tried inside the project folder, inside the app folder, same error. Inside the folder, it runs and build if you run `ng build --prod`, without the app's name, but it does not go to the dist folder, where I can run `npm publish`. See that it worked before, my guess is that I have forgotten the name used to build the app, I have changed the name, and now I cannot remember; but Angular is still use it somehow.
[image]

**Package.json from the project's folder**

```
{
  "name": "ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab",
  "version": "0.0.11",
  "description": "This is set of public packages from Miyagi-Do lab, related to mathematical modeling applied to life sciences.",
  "author": "Jorge Guerra Pires, PhD (jorgeguerrabrazil@gmail.com)",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "mathjs": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/mathjs": "^9.4.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/JorgeGuerraPires/ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab/tree/master"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/JorgeGuerraPires/ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://miyagi-do-lab.herokuapp.com",
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "javascript",
    "typescript",
    "eulersmethod",
    "numericalanalysis",
    "differentialequations",
    "bioinformatics",
    "appliedmathematics",
    "numericalsimulations",
    "biomathematics"
  ],
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: What is the log `angular-errors.log` saying?

Comment: this is the error. You mean the file I must open. I have to open. I will try!

Comment: added, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to the image you have posted, you run your `ng build ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab --prod` command from a terminal opened at `D:\Amazon ebook (sandbox)\modelos matemáticos na medicine e biologia (eboot)\Miyagi-Do-lab-sandbox\app`. At that location, angular can not find the project `ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab`.

Navigate your terminal to the location of your project and rerun the `ng build -ngx-mat-miyagi-dolab --prod` command and it should work.

Comment: "Navigate your terminal to the location of your project and rerun the" from the folder? tried! from several positions.

Comment: Tried inside the project folder, inside the app folder, same error. Inside the folder, it runs and build if you run `ng build --prod`, without the app's name, but it does not go to the dist folder, where I can run `npm publish`. See that it worked before, my guess is that I have forgotten the name used to build the app, I have changed the name, and now I cannot remember; but Angular is still use it somehow.

Comment: The `package.json`-file is relevant for npm. Can you open it inside your library project and look for a field called `name`. Would you post it`s content?

Comment: I am using the name from ´package.json´

Comment: Added, but I have already tried to see that, and also from the angular's project. My guess again: somewhere Angular is storing the old name. Tried on Google search, nothing